# Counting the number of ways a committee an be formed with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

A committee of 4 persons is to be chosen from 8 persons, including Mr Smith and his wife. Mr Smith will not join the committee without his wife, but his wife will join the committee without him. 
Calculate the number of ways in which the committee of 4 persons can be formed.

I am confused. Do I simply add the number of ways in which it can be formed without the two (6c4)+ the number of ways it can be formed with the two together (7c4) + The number of ways with only mrs smith (7c4).

But then I know that this is not correct because if I count them as 1 unit and choose 4 then there''ll be a case where the committee has 5 members. Also I feel like there are some overlaps.However, I do not know how to fix this. 0

Comment: `Without the two + with the two together + with only mrs. smith` is correct.  The numbers which follow however are incorrect.  For each case, ask yourself: How many people do you need to choose still?  Out of how many available?

Answer (score 0):

$^6C_2$ When Mr. Smith is to be included in committee .

$^7C_4$ When Mr. Smith is to be excluded from committee selection.

Add the 2 to get you answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to simply add.

But the number of ways in which both are included is $\binom 62$. As both of them are added and we have to pick 2 more from remaining 6.

After excluding Mr. Smith we left with 7 persons. Then Mrs. Smith included in committee and we left with 6 persons. We have to pick remaining 3 out of 6. So it is $\binom 63$.

Comment: And these two should be added to (6c4)?

Comment: @ShanLucien  That is correct.